# How to center text in Android AppCompat Toolbar when Activity is added to back stack?

Tags: android, xamarin, appcompatactivity

Trying to center a TextView in Android Toolbar, but when there's a view added to the back stack lost the centering. Seems the back item is not part of the toolbar and this causes the problem.

Here the xml for the toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
<FrameLayout
android:background="@color/primary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- This is a centered title -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginLeft="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Blah"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

When no back stack is centered:

[image: Centered TextView in Toolbar]

When Activity added to back stack shows the back button and text centering is lost:

[image: Lost centering when Activity added to back stack]

Comment: Did you try using a custom View for toolbar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a misperception of the center TexView that you are having.

The TextView is **on the center of its father(LinearLayout)** but is **NOT in the center of the Toolbar**.

When you add a new item to the Toolbar (the navigation item), it's pushing the FrameLayout, but the TextView keep on the center of its father the LinearLayout, **BUT IS NOT IN THE CENTER OF
THE TOOLBAR**.

The TextView is an item of LinearLayout, and is on the center of its container the LinearLayout.

LinearLayout is an item of the  FrameLayout.

FrameLayout is an item of the  Toolbar.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, got the idea of what's happening. But how i could center it in the toolbar, could you show an example?

Comment: The better approach that I can think right now  is add your own item navigation to the Toolbar, this way you can have a better control of the layout and center the textview to your preferences.


Other way not too elegant but works, is that you can detect when the navigation item is present and add some extra margin to the right of the textview that compensate the with of the navigation item, it'll look like is in the center.